# Shortcut to set package name in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm editing the source code of a class using IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

The IDE remind me to add package name. I know I can input `package com;` mannully, is there any shortcut that could let the IDE do it automatically?

Comment: Wouldn't intellij automatically add them (when you do `New` -> `Java Class`)

Comment: @user7 Yes. But the source code is copied from other places. Not through `new`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set cursor position to class name, use `Alt+Enter` -> `Set package name to`

Comment: Thanks. But sometime atfer entering `Alt+Enter`, there is no `Set package name to` option... Any idea?

Comment: Set cursor position to class name

Answer (score 0):

You might change the default  [java class template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) in the File and Code Templates, you should add the following line at start of template

> ```
>  #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
> ```

Comment: Thanks. The source code is copied from other places. Not through creating new file.